# cloudrun failing with find_vma failed

Tags: java, python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

my dockerfile for cloud run is as below.

```
FROM alpine:3.10.5

USER root

RUN apk update \
&& apk upgrade \
&& apk add --no-cache bash \
&& apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies unzip \
&& apk add --no-cache curl \
&& apk add --no-cache openjdk8-jre

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 \
&& python3 -m ensurepip \
&& pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \
&& rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi 

WORKDIR /opt/bin

RUN pip install Flask 'gunicorn>=20.0.1,<21' sqlalchemy pg8000 logger

COPY <some jar files>.jar /opt/bin/
COPY *.py /opt/bin/
RUN rm -r /root/.cache

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 2 --threads 8 --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm --timeout 30 http_test
```

when I run the docker image on cloudrun, i get the following error when I send a GET request to the URL given by Cloudrun:

```
020-05-04 13:22:14.551 ISTContainer Sandbox: Unsupported syscall membarrier(0x10,0x0,0x0,0x8,0x3e57651d89a0,0x3e57651d8a30). It is very likely that you can safely ignore this message and that this is not the cause of any error you might be troubleshooting. Please, refer to https://gvisor.dev/c/linux/amd64/membarrier for more information.
2020-05-04 13:22:14.603 ISTOpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Can't detect primordial thread stack location - find_vma failed
```

Have tried different alpine images, switched to gunicorn20.0.1 to avoid libc issues, no avail. Any suggestions, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your app doing? Is it possible you're exceeding the 32MB response limit?

Comment: Can you run this container locally in Docker?

Comment: the test code returns "Hello world" to the GET call. Since I posted this, I switched to ubuntu18.04 as the base image , code works find and I dont get the failed find_vma. I suspect it is a combination of alpine that is based on musl libc and openjre that is causing the find_vma errors -  just a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

while deploying the docker image in cloud run change the Execution environment to the second generation

**Second generation PREVIEW
File system access, full Linux compatibility, faster performance.**

had the same issue and I have fixed it, Hope it helps.